# Change password in android studio with firebase firestore as database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I wanted to build a function in which after user login, in their profile it will display their password and they can click on it to change their password. The problem is someone told me that password must not store in database and I should use updatePassword() method to change the password. However, in my case, I want to display the password first and then let user to change it. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: You can't change password unless user goes to Gmail page.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin what if I used a non-exist email to login? Then I cant change it?

Comment: If you want to authenticate with google account, you should use existing account

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello if you are using firebase I assume you must be using Firebase Authentication as well.
I will suggest not to show your user's password even to the user himself in the app and don't even store it anywhere.

To help them reset the password, please add a button with label Reset Password which when clicked will allow them to reset password via a link send through e-mail.

Just add the following code to do so:

```
resetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                oAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(user_email_string)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Reset link sent to your registered E-Mail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });

            }
        });
```

Just don't forget to declare FirebaseAuth at top of your code.

Comment: Glad to know. You can actually store the password in database but that involves adding firebase database rules and also a risk of reverse engineering and someone else getting the password..